# Docker: How to persist entrypoint in database image

Tags: docker

I have a base image called `base-image-A`

```
FROM postgres
ADD /scripts /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

In scripts is one script: `custom.sql`
I build the image and it's executed. It works.

Now I create an image derived from `base-image-A`:

```
FROM base-image-A
ADD ./different-scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

this works also fine. The original script and the new ones are executed.
But the problem happens when I try to mount

```
docker run -d ... -v ./different-scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ base-image-A
```

Now only the new scripts are executed and not the original script from base-image-a (custom.sql). It's probably overwritten by the mount. Is there a way to make this work and persist the script?

Comment: This is a guess, but I wonder if the postgres image runs scripts in subdirectories of the entrypoint directory. Then you could just mount to a subdirectory without overwriting the whole directory.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @sp0gg comment a solution would be to mount the `different-scripts` to a different directory (say `scripts`) and link the scripts in that directory to  `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Something like the following:

```
docker run \
--mount src=different-scripts,target=/scripts,type=bind \
base-image-A /bin/bash -c "ln -s /scripts/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d; \
/docker-entrypoint.sh postgres"
```

It should link your files before the initialization of the container.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are hiding the original scripts by mounting the new scripts directory on top of them, with:

```
-v ./different-scripts/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

As @sp0gg said, you could try this (I haven't tested it):

```
-v ./different-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/different-scripts/
```

The difference being that this mounts the new directory under the old one, rather than over the top of it. However, the `--mount` variant is preferable these days, as used in @b0gsub's answer.

Comment: docker-entrypoint.sh doesn't search in the sub-directories. It  does a bash loop over the set of files ``for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*;``

Comment: Then write your own script, using docker-entrypoint.sh as a base, that does descend into child directories -- it should only take a few minutes.